# How do I define a constant that can be used in multiple modules?

Tags: vba

I want to define the constants used in multiple modules with public const. However, An error will occur if public const is values defined in the following environment.
What should I do in this case?

There are two modules in my VBA project.
 1. sheet1 (sheet module): Main processing is described
 2. Class1 (classmodule): class used in the main processing　is Describe d

It can be solved by creating a standard module and writing only Public const variables in a standard module. But a module only contains public const values seems useless.

Comment: How is it useless? You're USING it to contain your constants... this is one of the most insane questions I've ever seen on here :D

Comment: No, it's not useless. That how it's done.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you're asking. You know already how to do it, you just don't like it.

Comment: I wanted to know best practices or alternatives.